# LDAP auth fails for some users

Tags: linux, ldap, authentication

Something weird is happening, some users are not able to authenticate via our LDAP to access services (SSH connection, Samba, etc.).

Their entries are in the LDAP and everything seems to be fine, I made a comparison with a working LDAP entry created with the same scripts only 5 minutes before, and the only differences I can see are the IDs/timestamps (`sambaPwdMustChange`, etc...)

If I do a `getent passwd | grep "username"` I find their record, but a ssh username@localhost fails (while again it works with other users created with the same script)

My log here /var/log/ldap/slapd.d shows error messages

```
Apr  9 14:09:48 je nslcd[3293]: [2fc6ce] lookup of user uid=someone,ou=People,dc=something,dc=com failed: Invalid credentials
```

But when I check their password on the phpldapadmin interfaces, it DOES match with the password I am entering. I am trying with a default password 123456789, which works for other users created with the same script.

Any ideas ?

EDIT 1

Authenticating with

```
ldapwhoami -vvv -D "uid=someone,ou=People,dc=something,dc=com" -x -W
```

and the password in question does return a `Success (0)`

EDIT 2

The authentication of these users against the same LDAP does work on many apps, like a Dokuwiki and a Rails application using the devise ldap-authenticatable gem. Only SSH and Samba seem to have problems.

Comment: Is there a service account involved? The error message does not necessarily mean that these are the invalid credentials of uid=someone. But rather that a search (lookup) was to be performed on uid=someone but failed due to invalid credentials... I.e. not the someone's credentials are invalid!

Comment: Well well well, you made me realize that those users can actually authenticate on other apps like a Dokuwiki and a Rails app (they also use LDAP auth). Seems that only SSH and Samba are failing.

Comment: @cornelinux I am not aware of any particular "service account" involved that would be different for those specific users that cannot connect. The authentication of users that can connect produce this entry in the same log (don't know if it's relevant) `[...] slapd[1813]: connection_read(27): no connection!`. Also the linux page of nslcd states `The default is to bind anonymously.` I'm not sure how I can check what's actually happening... Maybe I can run a Wireshark when I have some time.

Answer (score 0):

A similar problem had occured for me a while ago. When I looked at the `/var/log/messages` I have seen that sshd was complaining about an illegal user. If this is the case ssh will not log you in even if your password is correct. The solution for me to was to restart nscd

`service nscd restart`

This being said, getent works for you, so this might not be your solution.

Comment: Nothing particular in `/var/log/messages` (did the error show up at every attempt to connect ?). I have also tried restarting nscd but it didn't help. Thanks for suggesting though. The user(s) in question don't have any special characters or whatever in their usernames, and they don't look like reserved names, and ldap search with their full dn return only one result.

Comment: On some distributions these messages appear in /var/log/dmesg file, you might want to see that as well. The message appeared everytime I tried to login with the user.

Is the password hashing scheme same for all your users? For instance do you have MD5 on some SSHA on some? I have seen people having problems logging in when the password hashing scheme is different from that of the client OS.

Comment: Nothing worth mentionning in dmesg file I think. The password hashing scheme should be ssha everywhere. Maybe there are some exceptions, but I hvae checked and both users that can and cannot connect are under ssha.